# Parent - Child css tree

Tags: html, css

I am working on a tree structure hierarchy using CSS and I need a little help with it. I want to have two parent one child link up and I am unable to view the `border-left` defined in the CSS `::after` selector if I remove character `a` from content element.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daneuchar/6jsJv/).

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a hacky solution is to change `content:'a';` to `content:' ';`

http://jsfiddle.net/6jsJv/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
content:'';
```

Just try the empty parameter in `content:'';` rather than mentioning `content:'a';`. The `content` property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

Comment: tried that didn't work had to put display:block; property then null the content.